# Windows XP black screen in VMWare Workstation 12

Tags: windows-xp, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I have just installed VMWare Workstation 12, but since the VMWare Tools has been upgraded in the guest Windows XP, I can see only a black screen (the host is a Windows 7 on a Dell Inspiron 15 notebook). The booting process is visible, but the login screen is already black.

I can hear the login sound, I can start apps (in Unity mode), but every window is completely black.

After uninstalling the VMWare display adapter in Safe Mode, it works again in simple VGA mode. I have removed and reinstalled VMWare Tools and the screen is black again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It finally has been solved by turning 3D acceleration off at Display settings.

Comment: NICE! This just fixed my problem after running Windows Update on XP SP3 (also had unofficial SP4 + POSready2009 registry tweak to still get 2018 updates)